# Not able to use Angular-Material Directives

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I just included CDN URLs for Angular and Angular Material and trying to use Angular Material. But Seems like it is not working.

Comment: code Pen link - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYBjyj

Comment: can you provide us some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a angular module(eg: sampleApp) with `ngMaterial` as the dependant module.
2. Use this module `ng-app="sampleApp"`

Then it will work as expected.

Have a look at the codepen placed at: https://material.angularjs.org/#/getting-started